# How to use angular two way binding tag in spring boot Thymeleaf

Tags: angularjs, spring, thymeleaf

I have my image defined in json file as below

**certLogoURL : "/img/ocjp.gif"**

I am trying to display this in my thymeleaf template as

```
<img th:src="@{ {{certificate.certLogoURL}} }" > </img>
```

Image is not getting displayed in my webpage.

When I inspect the webpage it gets converted into

```
<img src="/img/ocjp.gif">
```

If I hard-coded the value as

```
<img th:src="@{/img/ocjp.gif}"> </img>
```

Image is getting displayed properly.

Could you please assist me on this?

Answer (score 0):

may be is bad the path, check http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html in 2.4. Link (URL) expressions